# Drop down list Selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I implemented a drop down in my ASP.net page .I put data sourse and bind drop down in page load event . I get the data  in the  drop down without any problem . But when i selected a value it always send index 1 value . I tried different values but it always sends the index 1 value to the backend

```
string[] parity = conData.GetParity();
                ddlParity.DataSource = parity.ToList();
                ddlParity.DataBind();



modemDetailsObj.Parity = ddlParity.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: call this inside `!Page.IsPostback`. Have you written the above code on page load. You might get duplicate values on every time make a postback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably binding the dropdown in postback again. You need to bind it in !Postback

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   string[] parity = conData.GetParity();
            ddlParity.DataSource = parity.ToList();
            ddlParity.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i getting this error " System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'IsPostback' and no extension method 'IsPostback' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Page"

Comment: try it >  `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: There was typo, IsPostback is IsPostBack